# update product price mass action updated with same price csv

Tags: product-attribute, price, magento2.4, multistore, csv

I’m trying to import a custom csv just with sku, store_id, price and special_price. It working good but the problem is when I did updates in a same product but with different stores.
I followed some referencies but the price still stuck on the last row.

Can anyone help me with some method that I can use to update price by store in the same sku?

Function that I'm using:

`$this->productAction->updateAttributes([$product->getId()], $updateAttributes, $rows['store_id']);`

Thanks...

Comment: Store specific prices can not be assigned to products in magento as price is global attribute. You can set different product price only on website level.

Comment: Thanks for your response..
Do you have any Idea that I can try to update price by store?

Comment: No, I don't have any idea about it. Also, it is practically impossible as all the price calculation at various points in Magento happens considering the global scope.